# retrieve a file list knowing the htaccess user and password

Tags: camera, file-listing

There's and IP camera problem here. I know the htaccess username and password. How can I retirieve a filelist from that camera. I'm not sure if this is a hacking question, because I know the username and the password, but if it is, please to be deleted.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are mentioning the .htaccess file, I'm assuming you are using the http protocol, on which you can't get lists of files, only if the webserver serves them (meaning, "Options +Indexes" is set). If the server serves the file lists, you could get the list with something like:

```
wget http://username:password@example.com/path/to/directory/
```

You'd have to replace wget with the program of your choice.

Comment: I've already downloaded some images from my camera with wget. But now I have to see all the files, because I need to know which one is filming. I'm using zoneminder and this is important for it.

Comment: Like I already said, you can onle see a list of files if the webserver serves such a list (meaning, "Options +Indexes" is set).